# Apache-POI sets values in Excel, but the formula of another cell is unable to work with the value until I manually press enter in the processing strip

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I wrote a programm, that writes values into a xlsx-file. At the first glance it seems to work like it should. But in my xlsx-file I've got a Formula in another cell that should works correct if I type in the value manually, but if my programm sets exactly the same value it doesn't work like it should. If I open the file manually after my programm wrote a value and confirm the wrote value by pressing the enter button in the processing strip it works like it should. There are no Exceptions thrown. My programm is writing in the cells N4 and O4. Here is the Excel Formula of the cell I'm talking about:

> =+MAX(;MIN(O4+(N4>O4);MAX(($N$2>$O$2);$O$2))-MAX(N4;$N$2))+MAX(;MIN(O4;MAX(($N$2>$O$2);$O$2))-MAX(;$N$2))*(N4>O4)+MAX(;MIN(O4+(N4>O4);MIN(($N$2>$O$2);$O$2))-MAX(N4;))+MIN(O4;MIN(($N$2>$O$2);$O$2))*(N4>O4)

N2 and O2 include preselected Values, that are compared with the values of N4 and O4. 
And here is my Java code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;


public class XLSXEditor {

public XLSXEditor(){

}

public void searchWriter(String path, JTable t1) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        File excel = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(1);
        int r = getNonBlankRowCount(path);
        String uname = "404";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        java.util.Date parsed = null;
        java.sql.Date date = null;

        //Datum Style
        CellStyle csDate = book.createCellStyle();
        CreationHelper createHelper = book.getCreationHelper();
        csDate.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("dd.mm.yyyy"));
        csDate.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csDate.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csDate.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csDate.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csDate.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_TURQUOISE.getIndex());
        csDate.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        //uname style
        CellStyle csUname = book.createCellStyle();
        csUname.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csUname.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csUname.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csUname.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csUname.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_TURQUOISE.getIndex());
        csUname.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        //time style
        CellStyle csTime = book.createCellStyle();
        csTime.setBorderTop(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csTime.setBorderBottom(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csTime.setBorderLeft(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csTime.setBorderRight(XSSFCellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        csTime.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LIGHT_TURQUOISE.getIndex());
        csTime.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("hh:mm"));
        csTime.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        csTime.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        csTime.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

        System.out.println(getFilledRows(t1));
        for(int i=0; i<getFilledRows(t1); i++){ 
            System.out.println(r);
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(r);
            //fill username column in xlsx file
            XSSFCell celluName = row.getCell(0, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

            if(celluName != null){
                r++;
            }
            if(celluName == null){                
                celluName = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(0);
                celluName.setCellStyle(csUname);
                uname = t1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString().charAt(0) +""+ t1.getValueAt(i, 1);
                celluName.setCellValue(uname);
                r++;
            }
            r--;
            //fill date column in xlsx file
            XSSFCell cellDate = row.getCell(5, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            System.out.println("r = " + r);
            cellDate = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(5);
            cellDate.setCellStyle(csDate);
            try{
                parsed = sdf.parse(t1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString());
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            date = new java.sql.Date(parsed.getTime());
            cellDate.setCellValue(date);


            //fill zeit von
            if(!(t1.getValueAt(i, 6).toString().equals("Standby not activated"))){
                XSSFCell cellTimeF = row.getCell(13, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                cellTimeF = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(13);

                String tf = t1.getValueAt(i, 3).toString();
                String timeF = tf.substring(0, 5);
                cellTimeF.setCellValue(timeF);
                cellTimeF.setCellStyle(csTime);
            }

            //fill zeit bis
            if(!(t1.getValueAt(i, 6).toString().equals("Standby not activated"))){
                XSSFCell cellTimeT = row.getCell(14, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
                cellTimeT = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(14);

                String tt = t1.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
                String timeT = tt.substring(0, 5);
                cellTimeT.setCellValue(timeT);
                cellTimeT.setCellStyle(csTime);
            }

            //set crosses
            XSSFCell cellStandbyP = row.getCell(7, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            XSSFCell cellStandbyA = row.getCell(8, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
            XSSFCell cellSpecial = row.getCell(9, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);

            if(t1.getValueAt(i, 6).equals("Standby not activated")){
                cellStandbyP = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(7);
                cellStandbyP.setCellStyle(csUname);
                cellStandbyP.setCellValue("x");
            }
            if(t1.getValueAt(i, 6).equals("Planned work")){
                cellSpecial = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(9);
                cellSpecial.setCellStyle(csUname);
                cellSpecial.setCellValue("x");
            }
            if(t1.getValueAt(i, 6).equals("Standby Activated")){
                cellStandbyA = sheet.getRow(r).createCell(8);
                cellStandbyA.setCellStyle(csUname);
                cellStandbyA.setCellValue("x");
            }
            r++;
        }            

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
        book.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
        book.write(fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
}
}
```

[in the picture u can see the columns, my programm is working with. I needed to cut out the other columns because of the german data security policy.. the columns are filled with strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsowM.png)

Comment: `String timeF = tf.substring(0, 5); cellTimeF.setCellValue(timeF);`: After that the cell `cellTimeF` always contains string (text) cell values. Seems it should contain numeric cell values instead so `MIN` and `MAX` is able working with them. Please update your question and show what `JTable t1` contains (at least a few rows) and what  kind of object `t1.getValueAt(i, 3)` returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your code part:

```
...
String timeF = tf.substring(0, 5); 
cellTimeF.setCellValue(timeF);
...
```

the cell content will always be string (text) cell content. This content the functions `MIN`and `MAX` cannot work with. Those functions needs numeric content. In `Excel` date and time also is numeric content only formatted as date-time. With default settings 1 = 1 day = 01/01/1900 00:00:00.  1 hour = 1/24, 1 minute = 1/24/60, 1 second = 1/24/60/60.

If `String timeF` is string of  format "HH:MM:SS", then [DateUtil.convertTime](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#convertTime-java.lang.String-) can be used to convert this string into a `Excel` valuable time.

Complete example which shows what not works and what works:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;

public class ExcelCalculateTimeValues {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
  CellStyle styletime = workbook.createCellStyle();
  styletime.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("hh:mm:ss"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("Start");
  sheet.getRow(0).createCell(1).setCellValue("End");
  sheet.getRow(0).createCell(3).setCellValue("Start");
  sheet.getRow(0).createCell(4).setCellValue("End");

  String[][] tableData = new String[][]{
   {"12:34:00", "22:45:00"},
   {"23:45:00", "01:34:00"},
   {"08:01:00", "13:23:00"}
  };

  int r = 1;
  for (String[] rowData : tableData) {
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r++);
   int c = 0;
   for (String cellData : rowData) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
    cell.setCellValue(cellData); //this sets string cell data
    cell.setCellStyle(styletime);
    cell = row.createCell(3 + c++);
    cell.setCellValue(DateUtil.convertTime(cellData)); //this sets datetime cell data
    cell.setCellStyle(styletime);
   }
  }

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellFormula("MIN(A2:A4)"); //cannot work because of string values in A2:A4
  sheet.getRow(r).createCell(1).setCellFormula("MIN(B2:B4)"); //cannot work because of string values in B2:B4
  sheet.getRow(r).createCell(3).setCellFormula("MIN(D2:D4)"); //will work
  sheet.getRow(r).createCell(4).setCellFormula("MIN(E2:E4)"); //will work

  workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelCalculateTimeValues.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

So with your code :

```
...
cellTimeF.setCellValue(DateUtil.convertTime(timeF));
...
```

and

```
...
cellTimeT.setCellValue(DateUtil.convertTime(timeT));
...
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation. You helped me so much again! :)