# apache poi write HH:mm:ss string to Excel Time data type

Tags: apache-poi

i used apache poi to rewrite a CSV file to Excel, for any string like HH:mm:ss, i need to convert it to the appropriate Excel data type so that user can apply sum() function on that column. i tried different datatype, but when i open the excel file i cannot sum that column the sum always showed as "0:00:00", even though clicking on that column in excel it showed as 'Time' data type,

here is my code:

```
CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
HSSFCellStyle timeStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();          
timeStyle.setDataFormat(creationHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("h:mm:ss"));
cell.setCellValue(column);
if (isTime(column)) {
  cell.setCellStyle(timeStyle);
}

private boolean isTime(String value) {
        try {
            dtf.parseDateTime(value);
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and here is my excel file
[image]

Comment: You are not giving complete example, so no complete answer is possible. But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404568/apache-poi-sets-values-in-excel-but-the-formula-of-another-cell-is-unable-to-wo/51406158#51406158. My suspicion is: `if (isTime(column)) { cell.setCellValue(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil.convertTime(column)); cell.setCellStyle(timeStyle);}` should work. It sets numeric cell value instead of string (text) cell value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the object `column` in your code is `String`, then the content of the cell will always be string (text) cell content after `cell.setCellValue(column)`. This content the function `SUM` cannot work with. Those functions needs numeric content. In `Excel` date and time also is numeric content only formatted as date-time. With default settings 1 = 1 day = 01/01/1900 00:00:00.  1 hour = 1/24, 1 minute = 1/24/60, 1 second = 1/24/60/60.

If `column` is string of  format "HH:MM:SS", then [DateUtil.convertTime](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#convertTime-java.lang.String-) can be used to convert this string into a `Excel` valuable time.

Complete example which shows what not works and what works:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;

public class ExcelCalculateTimeValues {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

  CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
  CellStyle styletime = workbook.createCellStyle();
  styletime.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("hh:mm:ss"));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("Time sting");
  sheet.getRow(0).createCell(1).setCellValue("Time");

  String[][] tableData = new String[][]{
   {"12:34:00", "22:45:00"},
   {"23:45:05", "01:34:40"},
   {"08:01:00", "13:23:00"},
   {"15:41:12", "23:23:22"}
  };

  int r = 1;
  for (String[] rowData : tableData) {
   Row row = sheet.createRow(r++);
   int c = 0;
   for (String cellData : rowData) {
    Cell cell = row.createCell(c);
    if (c == 0 ) {
     cell.setCellValue(cellData); //this sets string cell data
    } else if (c == 1) {
     cell.setCellValue(DateUtil.convertTime(cellData)); //this sets datetime cell data
    }
    cell.setCellStyle(styletime);
    c++;
   }
  }

  sheet.createRow(r).createCell(0).setCellFormula("SUM(A2:A"+r+")"); //cannot work because of string values in A2:A4
  sheet.getRow(r).createCell(1).setCellFormula("SUM(B2:B"+r+")"); //will work

  workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);

  if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelCalculateTimeValues.xls"));
  } else if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("ExcelCalculateTimeValues.xlsx"));
  }
  workbook.close();

 }

}
```

Comment: I was looking for "1 = 1 day = 01/01/1900 00:00:00. 1 hour = 1/24, 1 minute = 1/24/60, 1 second = 1/24/60/60.". Thank you!